# Event not getting fired in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

```
PnlImages.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <img id=\"img\" class=\"content\" src=\"" + url + "\" runat=\"server\" name=\"img\" onclick=\"return onClick(this);\" />"));


public void onClick(object sender)
{

}
```

debugger is not firing instead giving error "object expected".
Please help.

Comment: As far as I was aware, the literal control will just copy out the html to the client (not processing your runat="server" bit) and so the onClick is firing in the client javascript instead.  You may want to add an Image control instead of adding a Literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runat=\"server\" attribute is not an HTML attribute, but an instruction for ASP.Net to instantiate ASP.Net controls (System.Web.UI namespace) which generate not only HTML, but also ViewState, event handlers etc.

The onclick attribute refers to a JavaScript function that needs to be implemented in HTML or a linked .js file, and not an OnClick method in the C# back-end code.